# Is there a way to display the relationship between a categorical variable and multiple binary variables using a heatmap in R?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, heatmap, categorical-data

I'm working on a project trying to determine whether certain groups are more likely to adopt given products. While I could run a regression with group fixed effects for each individual product, the number of products is pretty high, which would make the report pretty tedious to get through. I was wondering if there is a way to generate a heatmap with the groups on the x-axis and the products on the y-axis that can display the relationship between these variables. It's proven surprisingly difficult. The data in question resembles the following

```
df<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,90,rep=TRUE)), group=sample( LETTERS[1:4], 90, replace=TRUE)) 

df[1,10,]

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 group
1   0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0   1     C
2   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1     C
3   0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0   1     B
4   1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0   1     C
5   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1     C
6   0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1   1     A
7   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0   0     B
8   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0   0     B
9   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0   0     A
10  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   0     C
```

I would like to show which group members (A, B, C, D) are more likely to use which product (X1-X10) in a single plot without having to print multiple regression tables. I would appreciate any help possibly incorporating the results into a heatmap.

Comment: You could calculate `Cramer's V` for each of your binary columns with your categorial variable and then heatmap these results.

Note: this would give you one "aggregated" measure per relationship, e.g. how much does group "correlate" with e.g. X1. It doesn't tell you which sepcific level of the group (A or B or C or D) relates how much with your X columns. So you wouldn't get a matrix of 4*10, but only 10 values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, for this project, I really need a 4 x 10 matrix as the output. I have to identify which groups are more or less likely to use a specific product.

Comment: Then you could calculate odds ratios. However this would only give you 3*10 matrix, since one of the groups would serve as your baseline category.

Comment: Otherwise if you really need a 4*10, then simply do a crosstable of groups with products to get proportions for how many of group X use product Y. This seems to be the most simple and straightforward solution.

Comment: Thanks! That does sound like the best course of action. Is there a specific function you'd recommend for generating the crosstable you suggested?

Comment: There are several packages that woudl allow for crosstabulation and where you probably also can get the results for all 10 variables in one go, e.g. the `expss` or `gt_tables` packages. But you can probably also calculate it by hand. Personally, I would use a tidyverse approach where I first group_by group and then simply calculate mean(variable) since it's all simple 0/1.

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(666)
df<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,90,rep=TRUE)), group=sample( LETTERS[1:4], 90, replace=TRUE)) 

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
```

which gives:

```
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 11
  group    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     0.6   0.48  0.56  0.4   0.36  0.56  0.56  0.6   0.4   0.44 
2 B     0.652 0.435 0.696 0.435 0.348 0.478 0.609 0.652 0.348 0.478
3 C     0.476 0.619 0.571 0.571 0.429 0.476 0.476 0.476 0.762 0.524
4 D     0.619 0.381 0.476 0.476 0.476 0.429 0.381 0.429 0.619 0.476
```

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out an alternative method earlier:

aggregate(data = df, . ~ group, mean)